# IntelliJ Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

In IntelliJ, I am running a cucumber Feature, using Right click "Run Feature" option.

I am getting this error

> classes/com/***/rest/test/feature1.feature Error: Could not find or
>   load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

When I check the run configuration I see that

> cucumber.api.cli.Main (Main class not found) and cucumber keyword is
>   in Red.

I have installed Cucumber-Java IntelliJ plugin and I have uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin several times in an effort to fix the problem. I also uninstalled IntelliJ idea and re-installed it just in case.

I have JDK 1.8.202, I downgraded to 1.8.171 just to see if that fixes the issue (Since some coworkers had that version working) . that didnt help either. Same test works fine in Eclipse, but I prefer to use IntelliJ since I more used to it. I have already checked other Stack overflow posts but didnt find any solution.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of Intellij IDEA Run configurations for Cucumber runner class. As I mentioned, in the Run Configurations screen, Main class cucumber is not found. The suggested thread given as Duplicate doesnt address this.

Comment: Have you downloaded the required dependencies? (I.e. cucumber-java)

Comment: yes i downloaded cucumber-java plugin for IntelliJ

Comment: Fixed by contacting Jetbrains support. Check that there are no erroneously specified java compiler options in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler. Can you build project by Maven? As a workaround try re-create project configuration by re-importing the project completely from Maven pom.xml file via File | New | Project from Existing Sources and selecting main parent pom.xml file to import from. If issue remains attach idea.log and build.log files https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085 after IDE restart and reproducing.

Comment: Re-importing from pom fixed the problem